# How disable write concern using bitnami/mongodb-sharded and docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, prisma, bitnami

I created a shared cluster using docker-compose sample file from bitnami/mongodb-sharded documents. like this:

```bash
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/containers/main/bitnami/mongodb-sharded/docker-compose.yml > docker-compose.yml
docker-compose up -d
```

I connected to DB using Prisma and this error occurred:

```
writeConcern is not allowed within a multi-statement transaction
```

Now I need to know hot to disable write concern using ENV Variables

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
# Copyright VMware, Inc.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: APACHE-2.0

version: '2'

services:
  mongodb-sharded:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:6.0
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-sharded
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=mongos
      - MONGODB_CFG_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-cfg
      - MONGODB_CFG_REPLICA_SET_NAME=cfgreplicaset
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  mongodb-shard0:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:6.0
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-shard0
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=shardsvr
      - MONGODB_MONGOS_HOST=mongodb-sharded
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=shard0
    volumes:
      - 'shard0_data:/bitnami'

  mongodb-cfg:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:6.0
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-cfg
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=configsvr
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=cfgreplicaset
    volumes:
      - 'cfg_data:/bitnami'

volumes:
  shard0_data:
    driver: local
  cfg_data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: You cannot disable it on the database side. It would need to be set in Prisma

Comment: Why do you create a sharded cluster with only 3 nodes - which is the absolute minimum you can have. You don't gain any redundancy or load sharing, you just increase the work for operating it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit This is for development on my local machine. main MongoDB is bigger

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the replicaSet settings and Default RW concern, e.g.

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.settings.getLastErrorDefaults.w = 1
cfg.settings.getLastErrorDefaults.wtimeout = 0
rs.reconfig(cfg)


db.adminCommand({ getDefaultRWConcern: 1 })

db.adminCommand({
   setDefaultRWConcern: 1,
   defaultWriteConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 3600 }
})
```

I don't think you can set it in any settings.

Comment: Where should I put this?
Should I manually set it after each docker-compose up? Can I add it inside docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I have no clue about docker. You must run these commands on the Mongo database after installing.